# Loglevel not logging in my React app after proper (?) installation and usage

Tags: reactjs, logging, log-level

I have a React app into which I'm trying to install a logger.  Loglevel seemed like a good bet and simple.

I installed it via NPM,

```
npm install -D loglevel
```

and included it in my React app (which, for what it's worth, was created with `create-react-app`)

```
import * as log from 'loglevel'
```

and tried to use it

```
    log.debug(`APP.JS: onAcknowledgeGameOver: NICKNAME: ${nickname}, GAMEID: ${gameID}, THIS.STATE.NICKNAME: ${this.state.nickname}`)
```

but I get no log in the console. What am I doing wrong?  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

Ah, you *have* to

```
log.setLevel('debug')
```

first -- apparently the default is some higher (lower) level